# GraphQL spec: Is the message field required in error responses?

Tags: reactjs, json, graphql, apollo-client

the recent graphql spec mentions the error response should return like so

```
{ 
    "errors": [ 
        { 
            "message": "Name for character with ID 1002 could not be fetched.",     
            "extensions": {
                "code": "NOT_FOUND",
            },
        }    
    ]
}
```

the spec does not specify if the message field is required, do i have to fill it for every error response?

I tried  returning an empty string for the message field but my webapp errors because of it

Comment: What do you expect from an error? A message explaining what went wrong. So why do you want to remove the error message from the error?

Comment: My backend has a lot of operations already using the old model, which does not adhere to the spec. adding a message to all of them at once would be a pretty big change, i'd like to avoid ruining the way my current operations work while also adopting the new model